# Tracking shared expenses

Tags: accounting, currency-converter

Say two people go on holiday and want to equally contribute to the costs e.g. food, car rental, accommodation etc. They do not have any joint credit cards, therefore they decide to pay for stuff alternately and somehow account/balance their contributions so that at the end of the trip they would have contributed as close to 50/50 as possible.

I am wondering if there is a software/website/app that would allow that. It would keep payment transactions recorded showing who paid, how much, in what currency and ideally it will show who has currently paid more and so who is the next one to pay.

Comment: So after a payment, as soon as Internet is available the app needs to sync payment information to each other's phone, right?

Comment: We tried https://kittysplit.com, it doesn't automatically track, but it's nice to split expenses, even not equally and calculates the most effective ways to settle all with less transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try app like

- Android

**Splitomatic** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splitter.trip&hl=en

This application provides sync and even bill split feature. But few features are paid through in app purchases.

**Splitwise**  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Splitwise.SplitwiseMobile&hl=en

Both Available for free on playstore.
I recommend **Splitwise** for better UI performance and its completely free.

or any similar application on iOS.

Comment: Could you please give a few details on those potential candidates? How do they meet the requirements, what about the price, what makes them recommendable?